# Two conditions for find_if

Tags: algorithm, c++11, vector, c++

In a `std::vector<unsigned int>`, I want to find the position of the element which is the maximum number smaller than a certain number. For example:

```
v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I want to find a number which is the maximum smaller than 8. That number is 7.

The following code is not correct but that is likely what I want to get.

```
std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator pnt = std::find_if (v.begin(), v.end(), [](const unsigned int& x) { return x < 8; && x == MAX; });
```

Comment: can you indent your second line, its not visible.

Comment: Your array is not always sorted, right? Or is it?

Comment: @jrok: Yes, always sorted.

Comment: Then just call std::lower_bound() to do a binary search; this "small detail" changes everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your vector is always sorted, then you can do it in logarithmic complexity

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 8); // first value >= 8
auto m = *((it != v.begin())? --it : it);
```

If your vector is unsorted, but can be modified, you could do it in 2 steps:

```
auto it = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x) { x < 8 });
auto m = *(it != v.begin())? std::max_element(v.begin(), it) : it);
```

If you can't modify your vector, you could do it by hand

```
auto max = 0;
for (elem: v) {
   if (elem < 8) 
       m = std::max(elem, m);
}
// m is now the max of all elements < 8
```

Both of the two final approaches have linear complexity. The latter can be generalized by using a [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) from the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library, but then you are already deep into template land, so only do that if you have repeated need for such magic.

Comment: In the first method, which `x < 8` will be chosen because there are 7 numbers smaller than 8.

Comment: @Shibli I don't understand your comment: `std::partition` will swap every element >= 8 to the far right of the returned iterator.

Comment: Don't you run into problems when vector v { 8, 9, 10} would be subjected to the ways you've just presented, for no value would be applicable, the latter method would return a incorrect value of '0'.

Comment: @hetepeperfan yeah, I guess I could "harden" the code a bit for such edge-cases, although for the empty range, `std::max_element` returns `v.begin()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function that checks wheter there a any values inside the vector and if not it throws an error. Then I would save every value that is lower than the maximal encountered but higher than the highest currently found. This is how I would implement it.

```
unsigned smaller_than ( const std::vector<unsigned int>& v, unsigned max) {

    bool intial_found = false;
    unsigned largest;
    unsigned i;
    for ( i = 0; i < v.size() ;++i){
        if ( v [i] < max ){
            largest = v[i];
            intial_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( ! intial_found ) {
        throw "oops";/*of course you make a Nice std::exception for this case*/
    }
    for (  ; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( v[i] < max && v [i] > largest){
            largest = v[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: throwing from a search routine if an answer it not found, is considered an anti-pattern: in the context of a search, failing to find an asnwer is not an error (not failing an invariant or post- or pre-condition) See Item 72 of C++ Coding Standards by Alexandrescu & Sutter.